# passing pointer ownership exception-safely

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, smart-pointers, raii

I have a situation where passing ownership of a raw pointer may throw an exception. There are several such blocks, and it would be inelegant to wrap each in a try/catch just to delete pointers which weren't accepted. Instead I'm using a `unique_ptr<A>` to manage my pointer with RAII:

```
unique_ptr<A> a(new A());
obj.take(a.get()); // pass ownership to obj, might throw
a.release(); // release pointer since obj is now responsible
```

So the idea behind this is to keep ownership of the raw pointer in the current function until it has been successfully passed to `somebody.take()`. This seems like a very nice pattern to me, but is it really? Any pitfalls I'm overlooking?

Comment: Isn't it better to pass `unique_ptr` instead of raw pointer?

Comment: Well, from `obj` I want to access `a` through a raw pointer, so I do need to `release()` at some point. I know `unique_ptr` is fast, but this is really about the single cpu cycle I may be saving. Good observation though since doing the `release()` in `obj.take()` might simplify my code further ;-)

Comment: It seems that [libc++'s implemetation of `std::list` also uses this pattern](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/list?revision=245806&view=markup#l1510).

Comment: This is the [scope guard](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Scope_Guard) pattern, essentially.

Comment: Why not pass in the unique_ptr by rvalue reference and call release inside?

Comment: @Victor: It's extremely likely your premise is flawed -- have you actually checked the source code or profiled alternatives to verify that a raw pointer saves you *anything at all* as compared to a `unique_ptr` in regards to how quickly you can dereference it? Given that your class `delete`s the pointer upon destruction, I would expect your program to result in *identical* code whether you used a `unique_ptr` or a raw pointer. (assuming you don't compile with optimization disabled)

Comment: I haven't verified it myself, but according to [Dr. Dobb's](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c11-uniqueptr/240002708), dereferencing a `unique_ptr` costs you one additional pointer dereference for the added level of indirection. Assuming by "compiled in Release mode" he means that optimization was enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, for anyone wondering, this is what I've done now to pass ownership of a pointer safely:

```
class C {
  A *mem_p = nullptr;

  /** take ownership exception-safely */
  void take(unique_ptr<A> &&a) {
    dangerous_stuff(); // may throw exception    
    this->mem_p = a.release();
  }

  ~C() { delete mem_p; }
}

void some_fun() {
  A *ptr = new A();
  C obj;
  obj.take(unique_ptr<A>(a)); // either obj owns ptr or it is freed
}
```

What I like about this is that it makes the ownership semantics *almost* explicit, or at least it alerts any user of `take()` to pay attention to the  lifetime of the argument.